# How to grouped data based on category field in react js?

Tags: javascript

I want to group the data based on category 
  field.

Input is:

```
var data: [
  {id:1, title:”title 1”, Category: “services”},
  {id:2 title:”title 2”, Category: “Blogs”},
  {id:3, title:”title 3”, Category: “services”},
  {id:4, title:”title 4”, Category: “services”},
  {id:5, title:”Services”, Category: “Blogs”}
]
```

Expected output is:

```
var out_data: {
     “services”:[
      {id: 1, title: ”title 1”},
      {id:3, title:”title 3”},
      {id:4, title:”title 4”}
    ],

  “Blogs”:[
       {id:2 title:”title 2”},
       {id:5, title:”Services”}
    ]
 }
```

Please provide any solution if you know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried up to now? "Please provide any solution." is not the right phrase. So, the proper way is to show us what have you tried and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one from the thousands of solutions :)

```
var data = [
    {id:1, title:'title 1', Category: 'services'},
    {id:2, title:'title 2', Category: 'Blogs'},
    {id:3, title:'title 3', Category: 'services'},
    {id:4, title:'title 4', Category: 'services'},
    {id:5, title:'Services', Category: 'Blogs'},
];

var out_data = {};

data.forEach(function(row) {
    if (out_data[row.Category]) {
        out_data[row.Category].push(row);
    } else {
        out_data[row.Category] = [row];
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Loadash's [_.groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#groupBy) function:

`npm i --save lodash.groupby`

Example:

```
var groupBy = require('lodash.groupby');

var data = [
  { id: 1, title: 'title 1', Category: 'services' },
  { id: 2, title: 'title 2', Category: 'Blogs' },
  { id: 3, title: 'title 3', Category: 'services' },
  { id: 4, title: 'title 4', Category: 'services' },
  { id: 5, title: 'Services', Category: 'Blogs' }
]

var out_data = groupBy(data, 'Category');

console.log(out_data);
```

Will output:

```
{ services: 
   [ { id: 1, title: 'title 1', Category: 'services' },
     { id: 3, title: 'title 3', Category: 'services' },
     { id: 4, title: 'title 4', Category: 'services' } ],
  Blogs: 
   [ { id: 2, title: 'title 2', Category: 'Blogs' },
     { id: 5, title: 'Services', Category: 'Blogs' } ] }
```